# How to emulate bootstrap grid's adaptiveness

Tags: html, css

I have two inline divs that share a parent container. The width's of the divs are 49% in order to align them horizontally. What I would like to do is after the parent container is resized down to a specific width. Both of the divs act as if they were block elements, that is occupy a new line and take up 100% of the container. I would not like to use bootstrap since this is the only feature I need from it and it seems pretty easy to emulate, just need some insight. Here is the basic layout

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">

  </div>
  <div class="cell">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Czech this out: https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle is simple:

```css
.container > div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container > div {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
}

/* the css from this point on is not important, i just added it for clarity */

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">
    First cell
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    Second cell
  </div>
</div>
```

The `800px` is the point where the layout changes. You can have as many `@media` queries as you want. Here is a full list of the [media features](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) you can use.